# Find all multiples of 3 & 5 between two limits - Complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to find all numbers between 1 and 10000000 (both inclusive). I tried two solutions

1. Brute Force Approach: Loop over all the numbers from 1 to 10000000, and find all which are divisible by either 3 or 5 or both.
2. Divide & Conquer approach: Having 4 counters (2 from start and 2 from end). 2 counters work on multiples of 3 and two work on multiples of 5. I am putting all multiples in a Set (I do not need Sorted elements, I only need elements , sorting increases my complexity as well).

But, the loop approach is taking smaller time than the 'Divide & Conquer approach' (10 times lesser approximately).
I searched for the solutions online as well. But, I could find loop approach only. Is there something I am missing in my approach which is increasing my execution time? Please point me to that. I started from a List, moved to Sorted Set, then finally settled to use HashSet, but seems to take time.

Here is what I tried.

`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Numbers divisible by 3 and 5:");

    nosDivisibleBy3And5();    // divide & conquer approach (approach to consider)

    nosDivisibleBy3And5BruteForce();

}

private static void nosDivisibleBy3And5BruteForce() {

    IntStream ar = IntStream.range(1, 10000001);  // start inclusive, end exclusive

    Integer[] array = ar.boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    int count = 0;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    /* 
     * Traversing array from 1 to 100, 
     * if it is either divisible by 3 or 5 or both, count it , print it. 
     * 
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i ++) {

        if((array[i] % 3 == 0) || (array[i] % 5 == 0)) {

            //System.out.println(array[i]);

            list.add(array[i]);

            count++;
        }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Brute Force Approach:");
    System.out.println("No of elements counted: " + count);

    //Collections.sort(list);

    //System.out.println("Elements: " + list);

    System.out.println("Time: " + (end - start));

}

private static void nosDivisibleBy3And5() {

    /* 
     * Set has all those numbers which 
     * are divisible by both 3 and 5.
     * 
     */

    Set<Integer> elementsSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

    int fr3,
    fr5,
    mid,
    count;

    fr3 = 2;   // fr3 indicates the index of the first value divisible by 3.
    fr5 = 4;   // fr5 indicates the index of the first value divisible by 5.
    count = 0;

    int end3 = 9999998 , // end3 indicates the index of the last value divisible by 3.
            end5 = 9999999;   // end5 indicates the index of the last value divisible by 5.

    /* Getting all the numbers from 1 to 100 from Intstream object */
    IntStream ar = IntStream.range(1, 10000001);  // start inclusive, end exclusive

    Integer[] array = ar.boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);

    /* 
     * Using divide and conquer approach , mid divides the array from 1 to 100
     * in two parts, on the first fr3 and fr5 will work, on the second part end3 
     * and end5 will work.
     */
    mid = (fr3 + end3)/2;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(fr3 <= mid && end3 >= mid) {

        elementsSet.add(array[fr3]);

        elementsSet.add(array[fr5]);

        elementsSet.add(array[end3]);

        elementsSet.add(array[end5]);

        fr3 += 3;
        fr5 += 5;
        end3 -= 3;
        end5 -= 5;
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Our approach");
    System.out.println("No of elements counted: " + elementsSet.size());


    //System.out.println("Elements:" + elementsSet);
    System.out.println("Time:  " + (end - start));
}
```

}

`

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) before you measure the execution time of any code. You need more accurate measurements before anything else.

Comment: for(long i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i += 3) {} -- no multiplications or remainder operations. Or am I misunderstanding something about this? You can do the same with 5, also. And you can do a simple trick to find those elements divisible by both 3 and 5.

Comment: @Sweeper, Thanks for the link. Though it is only the increasing input size which should decide the complexity, but here I can see the console hanging for my approach and lot for loop approach as I am increasing the input size. Time difference is calculated only to check the running time, no link with complexity I mean to have. It is only the console hanging I am concerned about, because I can see I am taking time there.

Comment: @NomadMaker. I think I should not be using Set here, just print the elements. In the below approach (not loop one), there is no multiplication or remainder operation, just counters increasing and decreasing and counters are themselves pointing to those elements which are multiples only, and are increasing by 3 or 5 respectively.

Comment: @Ashish ``(array[i] % 3 == 0)`` The ``%`` operator is the remainder operator. This is from your code. I still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @NomadMaker, please check the method `nosDivisibleBy3And5` . Divide & Conquer is implemented there. There are total two methods I have implemented. Remainder operation I have performed in the first method only.

Comment: @NomadMaker, my only concern is that when I am storing the elements in both the cases, i.e. BruteForce & Divide&Conquer, why Brute Force is faster even when I am increasing the input range.

Comment: Do you want to *count* them or find them?

Comment: @Bohemian, I want to find them and store them.

Comment: "Brute Force" and "Divide and Conquer" are normally algorithms for calculation/searching rather than storing. Perhaps that is the reason for my confusion.

Comment: @Ashish The numbers are `[3,5,6,9,10,12,15] + 15*n` for n = 0 to 666665, and then stop at 10 with n = 666666. All you need to do is add them to a list. The complexity is O(n), assuming that adding to a list is O(1). If not, allocate an array of size 4666667, and add them to the array. Time complexity is O(n) since indexing into an array is definitely O(1).

Comment: Do you want to have a `List<Integer>` of them?

Comment: @Bohemian, List<Integer> will be faster than Hashset, yes please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution, partially based on the excellent [answer by DelfikPro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64273796/5221149).

It simplifies the logic for calculating the array size, but adds more code to prevent the need for using the relatively slow `%` remainder operator, and eliminates the need to iterate over numbers that don't go into the result array.

As such, it should execute faster, though I haven't benchmarked to see if it actually does.

```java
static int[] multiplesOfThreeAndFive(int from, int to) { // both inclusive
    int count = ((to /  3) - ((from - 1) /  3))  // how many divisible by 3
              + ((to /  5) - ((from - 1) /  5))  // how many divisible by 5
              - ((to / 15) - ((from - 1) / 15)); // how many divisible by 15,  counted twice above
    
    int[] result = new int[count];
    int[] multiples = { 0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12 };
    
    int startIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(multiples, from % 15);
    if (startIndex < 0)
        startIndex = -startIndex - 1;
    for (int r = 0, offset = from / 15 * 15; r < count; offset += 15, startIndex = 0)
        for (int i = startIndex; r < count && i < multiples.length; i++, r++)
            result[r] = offset + multiples[i];
    return result;
}
```

*Tests*

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(multiplesOfThreeAndFive(1, 100)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(multiplesOfThreeAndFive(0, 100)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(multiplesOfThreeAndFive(29, 100)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(multiplesOfThreeAndFive(30, 100)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(multiplesOfThreeAndFive(31, 99)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(multiplesOfThreeAndFive(31, 101)));
```

*Outputs*

```
[3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 55, 57, 60, 63, 65, 66, 69, 70, 72, 75, 78, 80, 81, 84, 85, 87, 90, 93, 95, 96, 99, 100]
[0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 55, 57, 60, 63, 65, 66, 69, 70, 72, 75, 78, 80, 81, 84, 85, 87, 90, 93, 95, 96, 99]
[30, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 55, 57, 60, 63, 65, 66, 69, 70, 72, 75, 78, 80, 81, 84, 85, 87, 90, 93, 95, 96, 99, 100]
[30, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 55, 57, 60, 63, 65, 66, 69, 70, 72, 75, 78, 80, 81, 84, 85, 87, 90, 93, 95, 96, 99, 100]
[33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 55, 57, 60, 63, 65, 66, 69, 70, 72, 75, 78, 80, 81, 84, 85, 87, 90, 93, 95, 96, 99]
[33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 51, 54, 55, 57, 60, 63, 65, 66, 69, 70, 72, 75, 78, 80, 81, 84, 85, 87, 90, 93, 95, 96, 99, 100]
```

Answer (score 2):

HashSet takes a lot of time on hashing and checking if element already exists and is slower than bare ArrayList's `add()`

If your problem is really finding all the numbers that are divisible by 3 or 5, than you could use array with predetermined length:

```java
int from = 1;
int to = 1000000;
int d3 = (to / 3) - (from / 3) + (from % 3 == 0 ? 1 : 0); // how many divisible by 3
int d5 = (to / 5) - (from / 5) + (from % 5 == 0 ? 1 : 0); // how many divisible by 5
int d15 = (to / 15) - (from / 15) + (from % 15 == 0 ? 1 : 0); // how many divisible by 15

int[] array = new int[d3 + d5 - d15]; // counted 15's twice

int offset = 0;
for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) array[offset++] = i;
}
```

Comment: I agree with your first statement. It seems Hashset is taking a lot of time. I think I should only print it. Would see the data structure I can use though to have elements stored as well. The code part you posted is the loop approach, so according to you, I should follow loop approach?

Comment: Nice answer, though the array length calculation can be simplified a bit, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64275028/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

If returning a `List<Integer>` is the goal, you could have a O(1) time and space solution by extending `AbstractList` and implementing an `iterator()` that keeps track of the index of the next number, and implement `get(int index)`, `size()`, `equals()`, `hashCode()` etc and iterator’s methods all by calculation based on the max number.

The List would be immutable (simply wrap using `Collections. unmodifiableList()`), but would fulfil the contract of List.

All done without actually storing any of the numbers.

Comment: Nowadays, with Java 8, it should return a `Stream` instead of an `Iterator`. Which actually means that it should implement a [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html), or rather a [`Spliterator.OfInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html). That `Spliterator` can easily implement [`trySplit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html#trySplit--), allowing parallel processing. The `Spliterator` would have all characteristics except `CONCURRENT`.

Comment: @Andreas you would `extend AbstractList` and override `iterator()` (and a few other methods like `size()` etc) which gives you `stream()` (and other related Java 8 methods) for free because they are implemented in `Collection` and all ultimately use the impl’s Iterator.

Comment: Why would you subclass `AbstractList` to create a `List` implementation that violates the contract of [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for most of the methods? That is a very bad solution. Or did you somehow intend to implement `get(int index)`, which is not an optional method?

Comment: @Andreas I didn’t think I needed to say it...  of course it would be an immutable list (simply by utilising `Collections.unmodifiableList()`), and if course it must implement `get(int index)` (I was even going to post an impl, but decided I wasn’t going to do all of OP’s work), which I would use in the iterator, which would then only need store the index (a neat impl IMHO). Such a list *would* fulfil the contract of `List`. That was always my intention.